# How can I create a non-http proxy with Twisted

Tags: python, twisted

How can I create a non-http proxy with Twisted. Instead I would like to do it for the Terraria protocol which is made entirely of binary data. I see that they have a built-in proxy for HTTP connections, but this application needs to act more like an entry point which is forwarded to a set server (almost like a BNC on IRC).
I can't figure out how to read the data off of one connection and send it to the other connection.

I have already tried using a socket for this task, but the blocking recv and send methods do not work well as two connections need to be live at the same time.

Comment: Are you trying to build a load balancer?

Comment: @tMC No. All the connections will go to one server. Kind of like a BNC on IRC. You connect to the BNC while it connects to the IRC server. If you lose your connection to the BNC, you can just reconnect without losing your session.

Comment: What protocol(s) are you hoping to proxy?

Comment: You should make this question more specific: Which protocols do you want? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @tMC I am hoping to proxy the Terraria (game) protocol. It consists of binary data.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the game, or how it works, but I think you'll be hard pressed sync a new connection to the 'BNC' with a current connection from the BNC to the server.  It COULD be possible if the game supported it- but its not likely.  If its TCP traffic, its likely the game protocol depends on specifics of the TCP protocol, NOT something you can easily take over. In fact, TCP has mechanisms in it to prevent this. IRC is much easier because it just relays text; its very far removed from the network layer. (HTTP is just text as well)

Comment: @tMC I already understand the protocol to a decent extent and by logging with WireShark, I can tell you that it won't be that hard. There is not constant "chatter" between the two. The client only sends to the server as needed and the server never requests data from the client.

Comment: Well, if the proxy machine maintains the connection to the server, and thus preserves sequence numbers, I sounds like it might be possible.  Of course all the traffic will look like its coming from the proxy.  I don't know anything about twisted, sorry, but I think you could prototype it pretty quickly with scapy if you wanted.  Else, just lift the HTTP proxy from twisted and remove all the HTTP pieces from it? Beware, of course, of the performance penalty of taking a packet from the kernel, to user-land and back again; going both directions.

Comment: @tMC Scapy seems like overkill for something like this, but I will keep that in mind. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you just want to forward traffic use a layer3 tunnel, not twisted. In Twisted you have to actually implement the protocol (ie actually understand what you're forwarding), which seems useless to you.

Comment: You don't *have* to.  You can have a stupid proxy that just pushes bytes around.  MostAwesomeDude even pointed out that one of these comes with Twisted, twisted.protocols.portforward.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several different ways to create proxies in Twisted. The basic technique is built on peering, by taking two different protocols, on two different ports, and somehow gluing them together so that they can exchange data with each other.

The simplest proxy is a port-forwarder. Twisted ships with a port-forwarder implementation, see http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.protocols.portforward.html for the (underdocumented) classes `ProxyClient` and `ProxyServer`, although the actual source at http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/tags/releases/twisted-11.0.0/twisted/protocols/portforward.py might be more useful to read through. From there, we can see the basic technique of proxying in Twisted:

```py
def dataReceived(self, data):
    self.peer.transport.write(data)
```

When a proxying protocol receives data, it puts it out to the peer on the other side. That's it! Quite simple. Of course, you'll usually need some extra setup... Let's look at a couple of proxies I've written before.

This is a proxy for Darklight, a little peer-to-peer system I wrote. It is talking to a backend server, and it wants to only proxy data if the data doesn't match a predefined header. You can see that it uses `ProxyClientFactory` and endpoints (fancy `ClientCreator`, basically) to start proxying, and when it receives data, it has an opportunity to examine it before continuing, either to keep proxying or to switch protocols.

```py
class DarkServerProtocol(Protocol):
    """
    Shim protocol for servers.
    """

    peer = None
    buf = ""

    def __init__(self, endpoint):
        self.endpoint = endpoint
        print "Protocol created..."

    def challenge(self, challenge):
        log.msg("Challenged: %s" % challenge)
        # ...omitted for brevity...
        return is_valid(challenge)

    def connectionMade(self):
        pcf = ProxyClientFactory()
        pcf.setServer(self)
        d = self.endpoint.connect(pcf)
        d.addErrback(lambda failure: self.transport.loseConnection())

        self.transport.pauseProducing()

    def setPeer(self, peer):
        # Our proxy passthrough has succeeded, so we will be seeing data
        # coming through shortly.
        log.msg("Established passthrough")
        self.peer = peer

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.buf += data

        # Examine whether we have received a challenge.
        if self.challenge(self.buf):
            # Excellent; change protocol.
            p = DarkAMP()
            p.factory = self.factory
            self.transport.protocol = p
            p.makeConnection(self.transport)
        elif self.peer:
            # Well, go ahead and send it through.
            self.peer.transport.write(data)
```

This is a rather complex chunk of code which takes two `StatefulProtocol`s and glues them together rather forcefully. This is from a VNC proxy (https://code.osuosl.org/projects/twisted-vncauthproxy to be precise), which needs its protocols to do a lot of pre-authentication stuff before they are ready to be joined. This kind of proxy is the worst case; for speed, you don't want to interact with the data going over the proxy, but you need to do some setup beforehand.

```py
def start_proxying(result):
    """
    Callback to start proxies.
    """

    log.msg("Starting proxy")
    client_result, server_result = result
    success = True
    client_success, client = client_result
    server_success, server = server_result

    if not client_success:
        success = False
        log.err("Had issues on client side...")
        log.err(client)

    if not server_success:
        success = False
        log.err("Had issues on server side...")
        log.err(server)

    if not success:
        log.err("Had issues connecting, disconnecting both sides")
        if not isinstance(client, Failure):
            client.transport.loseConnection()
        if not isinstance(server, Failure):
            server.transport.loseConnection()
        return

    server.dataReceived = client.transport.write
    client.dataReceived = server.transport.write
    # Replay last bits of stuff in the pipe, if there's anything left.
    data = server._sful_data[1].read()
    if data:
        client.transport.write(data)
    data = client._sful_data[1].read()
    if data:
        server.transport.write(data)

    server.transport.resumeProducing()
    client.transport.resumeProducing()
    log.msg("Proxying started!")
```

So, now that I've explained that...

I also wrote Bravo. As in, http://www.bravoserver.org/. So I know a bit about Minecraft, and thus about Terraria. You will probably want to parse the packets coming through your proxy on both sides, so your actual proxying might start out looking like this, but it will quickly evolve as you begin to understand the data you're proxying. Hopefully this is enough to get you started!

Comment: This simple recipe is another great example of non-protocol specific proxy.

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/502293-hex-dump-port-forwarding-network-proxy-server/